# Laravel Redirect doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, redirect, laravel

When I run from the controller for www.mysite.com/login

```
return Redirect::to_action('profile');
```

it brings the user to www.mysite.com/index.php/profile

I've tried it with Redirect::to('profile'); but that doesn't work either.
Redirect::home(); brings me to www.mysite.com/index.php which lead me to believe that my mod_rewrite was somehow not working but I have 

     RewriteEngine on

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

in the .htaccess under public.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Laravel to generate links minus the index.php prefix, you need to configure it correctly in addition to having the .htaccess file.

It's easily overlooked, so make sure you've set `'index' => '',` in your `application/config/application.php`. It's on line 42 in the default config.